# Corrupted files generated by Arduino with SdFat library. How to avoid that?

Tags: sd-card

I got:

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove
- http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/Stackable_SD_Card_shield_V3.0 (set to 5V logic)

with this [sketch](http://pastie.org/10691360) using SPI/SdFat+OneWire/DallasTemperature+EmonLib and no matter what I try I got corrupted files like [this](http://pastie.org/10691362).

I even haven't attached my sensors yet :(
I have tried with 3 SD cards so far, each formatted with [SD Memory Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) and each one has this problem.

There is a separate question like that ([Corrupted files generated by Arduino with SD library. How to avoid that?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57714/corrupted-files-generated-by-arduino-with-sd-library-how-to-avoid-that)) but it concerns SPI confict but here SD is my only SPI device on the bus.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SD shield has CS on D4, not D10

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: yes, it did solve it